# Ubuntu 14.04 'sudo' and networking not working

Tags: 14.04, networking, sudo

I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 today and I have two problems

1) When ever i do 'sudo' followed by a command the system just stalls, nothing from 'sudo ls' to 'sudo apt-get install ... ' etc  works. The system just waits and waits.

2) My networking is never starting. I cannot connect to internet at all. no ethernet and no wireless. The tray icon is missing. /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state tells my networking is enabled. I cannot edit any system files because I cannot 'sudo'!

however, when I enter recovery mode, everything seems to be fine. 'sudo' works and networking also works!!!. Can somebody help me please.

Comment: 1.Could you please show the command(s) output? 2.Only one question at a time.

Comment: Does it ask for the password?

Comment: sudo is not asking for password.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a hostname resolution failure.

Did you change your hostname recently?

#### Yes

---

In recovery mode, update your `/etc/hosts` with your new hostname so it points to 127.0.0.1, like so:

```
127.0.0.1  myNewHostname
```

Also make sure that your `hostname` file is correct.

#### No

---

Your `localhost` is probably not resolving properly. In recovery mode, check your `/etc/hosts` file and make sure lines like these exist:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 myHostname
```

If it doesn't, create it.

Comment: I checked my /etc/hosts file and found that it has '127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 myHostname'. So I changed the second line to '127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 myHostname' . But it is not helping

Comment: @Coniferous Don't remove, add.

Comment: Hai I have added a third line now '127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 myHostname 127.0.0.1 myHostname' , still the problem persist.